# Customer Attribute is missing in admin after data migrtion version(1.9.0.1 to 2.1.7)

Tags: magento-2.1, data-migration

I Have successfully migrated the Magento 1 to Magento 2 using the data migration tool after the migration I don't find the customer attributes in admin.

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Customer Attributes is a Magento Commerce (formally Enterprise) feature - if you had this on a Magento Open Source (formally CE) store, then I'm guessing you had an extension installed that allowed for this that you don't now have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Customer Attributes is a Magento Commerce (formally Enterprise) feature - if you had this on a Magento Open Source (formally CE) store, then I'm guessing you had an extension installed that allowed for this that you don't now have.